# How to use function pointers in C using structs?

Tags: c, struct, mingw, function-pointers

I'm trying to print time using function pointers and structs. It doesn't give any error. It works first but later "Test.exe stopped running!".

My files are: Random.c Random.h , Randomness.c Randomness.h, Test.c

Random.h

```
struct RANDOM {
    char* date;
    char* (*Date) (struct RANDOM*);
    void (*Write) (struct RANDOM*);
};
typedef struct RANDOM* Random;

Random CreateRandom();
char* DateOfNow(const Random);
void WriteDate(const Random);
```

Random.c

```
char* BringTime(){
    char* buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    time_t now = time(0);
    strftime(buff, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",localtime(&now));

    return buff;
}

Random CreateRandom(){
    Random this;
    this = (Random) malloc(sizeof(struct RANDOM));  
    this->date = BringTime();

    return this;
}

char* DateOfNow(const Random this){
     return this->date;
}

void WriteDate(const Random this){
    printf("\n\n Date is: %s", this->date);
}
```

Randomness.h

```
struct RANDOMNESS{
    Random super;
};

typedef struct RANDOMNESS* Randomness;

Randomness CreateRandomness();
```

Randomness.c

```
Randomness CreateRandomness(){
    Randomness this;
    this = (Randomness)malloc(sizeof(struct RANDOMNESS));
    this->super = CreateRandom();

    return this;
}
```

Test.c

```
int main() {

    Randomness rnd = CreateRandomness();
    printf("works till here");
    rnd->super->Write(rnd->super);
}
```

Output is: works till here

After that output it stops running "Test.exe stopped running".

I tried `printf("%p", rnd->super)` It gave me the address. So maybe there is a problem with `Write(rnd->super)` function.

Comment: It looks ok. There is probably an issue in an unrelated part of the code. try valgrind (if warnings do not reveal anything).

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind typedefs (`Random`, `Randomness`).  It almost always makes your code harder to read and maintain.  (And the example code is no exception.)

Comment: You never initialize the function pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign function pointers to the member fields in the structure:

```
Random CreateRandom(){
    Random this;
    this = (Random) malloc(sizeof(struct RANDOM));  
    this->date = BringTime();
    // assign function pointer to actual functions
    this->Date = &DateOfNow; 
    this->Write = &WriteDate;

    return this;
}
```

For sure, prototypes of `DateOfNow` and `WriteDate` should be available ahead of `CreateRandom` definition.

Note: you may write `this->Date = DateOfNow;` (without `&` as `&` with function identifier is a surplus).

Answer (score 0):

Your create function is incomplete:

```
Random CreateRandom(){
    Random this;
    this = (Random) malloc(sizeof(struct RANDOM));  
    // Content of the memory is undefined!
    this->date = BringTime();
    // What about Write() and Date()? <<<======= ERROR IS HERE
    return this;
}

...

Randomness CreateRandomness(){
    Randomness this;
    this = (Randomness)malloc(sizeof(struct RANDOMNESS));
    this->super = CreateRandom();

    return this;
}

...

int main() {

    Randomness rnd = CreateRandomness();
    printf("works till here");
    rnd->super->Write(rnd->super); // << using unspecified values is undefined behaviour.
}
```

You assign some value to `date` but not to `Date`and `Write`.
This means you have some useful value in `rnd->super` but content of `rnd->super->Write` is undefined.

If you want to use the `Create*` functions as a kind of constructor, you must also set the function pointers correctly.